# Storing tutorial videos on iOS and Android applications locally?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, local-storage

I have an upcoming project where I needed to store tutorial videos locally for iOS and Android. Initially, I will be using a hybrid-app, Cordova.

Just wanted to ask experts here if this is possible and what is the max size? Videos will have around 20 or more depending on topics.

NOTE: The app will be running on a old smart-phones, with no to minimal internet connection. As this will be given to a remote location.

Comment: Its a bad idea to store videos locally Since they can be huge in size . And you can not update the local media without a new update of app .. You should be using a Server to serve the videos .. Or you can use You Tube API ..

Comment: you can consider making the videos significantly reduced quality with high compression, but again as @ADM says, you should have the videos served and cached on the device automatically

Comment: What I forgot to mention, the app is stand-alone on a old smart-phone that has no internet connection.